# Is it possible to grant a specific privilege to a user without sudo?

Tags: sudo, apache-httpd, root, privileges

I'm not going to add `sudo` in my Buildroot environment for RPi 3 B+ since I just need `apache2` to update my system time with `date -s TIME`.

Is there a way to grant this permission without installing and configure `sudo`?

Comment: A tool like `sudo` can, if configured correctly, provide a method of tightly controlling privileged access. (Often it's left wide open so admin user accounts can do anything. Here that's not what you'd want.) If you don't use `sudo` or an equivalent such as `doas` you'll need to reinvent something similar yourself anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two ways of doing this.

For both you'll need to write and compile a program that does the work you want (eg calling `stime(2)`).  You can't just call `date` directly.

And you'll need a group that only the user that runs apache2 (`www-data` ?) is in.  In both cases we limit the ability to execute the program to the specified group, so no one else can run it.

Option 1: Make it setuid root

```
chown root.thegroup yourprogram
chmod 4710 yourprogram
```

Now only people in the group can execute the program and it runs with effective root.

Option 2: Use capabilities

```
chown root.thegroup yourprogram
chmod 710 yourprogram
setcap cap_sys_time=pe yourprogram
```

This grants your program the rights to call settimeofday(2), stime(2) and adjtimex(2) without needing root permissions.

But the `sudo` solution is the simplest...

Comment: set uid for people that don't like to manipulate bits in their head, or that realise that they often make mistakes: `chmod ug+x,u+rw,u+s yourprogram`. It will calculate the bit pattern for you. It works with Gnu `chmod` and other good `chmod`s.

Comment: Both solutions require a statically linked executable (so no scripts, or interpreted languages).